# Laravel-Redis Cluster ServerException in Pipeline.php line 102

Tags: php

I have a Redis cluster, 3 master with 1 slave each. Most of the time when i send redis command i'll be redirected to another master.

```
127.0.0.1:7000> get mytest:1
-> Redirected to slot [7306] located at 127.0.0.1:7001
"test1"
127.0.0.1:7001> set mytest:2 "test2"
-> Redirected to slot [11497] located at 127.0.0.1:7002
OK
127.0.0.1:7002> set mytest:3 "test3"
OK
127.0.0.1:7002> set mytest:4 "test4"
-> Redirected to slot [3119] located at 127.0.0.1:7000
OK
127.0.0.1:7000>
```

This redirection is causing problem when issuing multiple commands in laravel

```
$redis = Redis::connection();

    $redis->pipeline(function($pipe) {
        $pipe->set("test:1", "test1");
        $pipe->set("test:2", "test2");
        $pipe->set("test:3", "test3");
    });
```

below is the error

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

1/1
ServerException in Pipeline.php line 102:
MOVED 2233 127.0.0.1:7000
```

note: sending one command has no problem